# Feed through capacitor

Tags: capacitor, emc

I have 2 feed through capacitor NFM21PC475B1A3 & NFM21PC105B1C3. These haven't the same capacitance. I want to separate them but I can't measure. Help me what should I do?

Comment: Search for the part numbers, it will tell you the values.

Comment: @awjlogan oh! Some of them have been mixed accidentally. Their shapes are same. So I can't separate.

Comment: Is there nothing printed on the components?

Comment: @awjlogan Nope! It looks like a ceramic capacitor but it has 4 lead.

Comment: Got it! Didn't mean to be glib, by the way :)

Comment: @awjlogan so what's your mean?

Answer (score 1):

Buy some cheap $5 multimeter which can measure capacitance.
One capacitor is 4.7uF and the second 1uF. So even the cheapest multimeter with capacitance measurement capability will help to distinguish them.

Comment: I have a multimeter. But it's not the same as capacitor. when I measure the two larger leads multimeter shows 0.

Comment: @parisa-far make sure it has capacitance measurement on it, and make sure the leads are in the right place

Comment: @parisa-far those larger pads are shorted together, look at the datasheet. Measure capacitance between one of the outter pads an pad in the middle.